# Watchkit OS 2 , AVSpeechSynthesizer

Tags: extension-methods, watchkit, apple-watch, avspeechsynthesizer

i want add AVSpeechSynthesizer in my watchkit codes

and how can i do in watch kit os 2 for read Avfoundation is that possible or i need to convert avfoundation to Mediaplayer or ....

```
AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
    speechPaused = YES;
    AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:@""];
    utterance.rate = 0.15;
    utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"it_IT"];
    [synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
```

how its work in watchkit os2

Answer (score 0):

No. AVFoundation isn't available for watchOS apps.

The closest thing you could do is use `WKInterfaceMovie` to play prerecorded audio clips in your watch app.

Source: [watchOS 2 Transition Guide: Available System Technologies](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleWatch2TransitionGuide/LeverageSystemTechnologies.html)